# Why is my LCD I/F PIN ADAPTER won't work

Tags: lcd

I bought this on the store near us. Here is the PDF for it.

https://www.e-gizmo.net/oc/kits%20documents/new%20LCD%20with%20converter/LCD%20IF%20pin%20adapter.pdf

I followed the instructions below and uploaded the code and all I've got is this
[image: Uploaded]

I've reconnected it and used a different jumper wires, still the same result.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);

void setup(){
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.print("ntest");
}

void loop(){

  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(millis()/1000);

}
```

Comment: How did you wire the LCD to your Arduino? Which model of Arduino are you using?

Comment: Exactly as like with the pdf. I'm using arduino uno, I never had issues with my microcontroller and the code seems to compile and get uploaded to the board seemingly. I've tried to change the pins on the code and on the actual it still does not work.

Comment: The PDF shows 2 different ways of connecting the display to the Arduino. Which method are you using?

Comment: I tried both and it's the same output.

Comment: I guess no one knows.